# Issues with wireless connection to router (IP assignment?)

Tags: networking, wireless

I reinstalled Ubuntu 16.04 on my computer and now have issues connecting to the internet at work. Access to my home wifi was fine.

I can: Connect to the wifi. The router sees there's a connection.
I can't: Access the internet or even the router setup page. This works on all other computers on the network.

I've rebooted the router and my computer several times. 
I have noticed that under "Connection information", my local IP is different from the one that the router website says I'm assigned to and in fact the IP address Ubuntu tells me I have is our network printer IP. So I can see how this could cause a problem, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

I also tried to change some DNS settings yesterday as DNS leaks were found with the vpn connection I sometimes use. I'm pretty sure I undid all changes, but there might be something hanging on. I'm not quite sure how to check for that.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Edit: In the end I did a factory reset of the router. This worked, but only for one of its two wireless networks. Who knows. I am happy enough.